# css not served using express.js

Tags: node.js, express, less

I'm using express 4.x and less-middlesware, I have a main file (handlebars):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

and my server looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var less = require('less-middleware');
var path = require('path');


var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var app = express();

app.set('views' , __dirname + '/server/views');
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main' ,
    layoutsDir: 'server/views/layouts',
    extname: '.hbs'
    }));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(less(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.get('*' , function(req , res){
    res.render('index', {message: 'Hi'});
});

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);
```

The page is served fine but i get this message regarding css:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://localhost:3000/public/css/styles.css".

What am i missing?

Comment: remove `public/` from your `link` tag. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked only when i put '/' infront of it: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">